# I need help with transparent images in blender,

Tags: texturing, texture-coordinates

I am new to blender, I moved to this animating program from adobe animate(flash) recently.

In blender I have set up a sphere, but I want to add eyes onto this sphere like a face.
Whenever I try to do this by adding materials it just merges them both and makes a weird effect. What I want is to be able to have this eye rig on top of the current texture of the sphere. I wish to be able to set up a slider to change the eye emotions and the position of the eyes as well. I have linked a image which visualizes it
[image: The image which shows what i've gotten so far and what I want..]

Sorry if I sound sort of picky, I've been having a go at this for a few hours now with no way of doing it found on my own.

Comment: You could probably get the same effect using greasepencil strokes. https://www.blendernation.com/2019/11/18/grease-pencil-eye-rig-tutorial/#prettyPhoto

Comment: is it possible to add this on a 3d rig?

Comment: Yes, just make it so that it has its origin set to the centre of the ball and it always turns to face the camera with the track to constraint modifier.

Comment: I am thinking that both the outside and the inside of the black lines are transparent. Is this the case?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard The inside of the eye is white with a black outside and the rest of the eye image is transparent, the sphere has color